# PaperClip check existence before process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg, paperclip

I'm trying to skip `PaperClip` process if my music has been deleted.

Basically when I upload a music, I want to destroy every single piece of this uploaded file if something went wrong. This operation is delayed and done by `ffmpeg`. Another task is delayed to attached picture to my music.

Unfortunately, `PaperClip` process (to attach the picture) has already been delayed when I destroy bad musics. This means when the process starts the source doesn't exist anymore.
This blocks my `delayed_jobs` and I have to destroy it manually.

I'm using [Delayed_paperclip](https://github.com/jrgifford/delayed_paperclip/) to create those delayed jobs.

How can I check if the source exists before processing?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are dealing with is called `race condition`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

*Assuming, you are donig something like:* `@my_instance.delay.method`

You might want to pass the id of the object you are attaching an image to it to a `perform` method

```
def perform(obj_id)
  begin
    MyObj.find(obj_id)
  rescue
    # => do your stuff here
  ensure
    # => ensure your stuff here
  end
end
```

Example: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/#custom-jobs

Comment: I was enjoy to early. It's working for job that I call manually but I've some troubles to apply it to jobs linked to `PaperClip`.

Comment: It's `delayed_paperclip` which manages delayed job creation. Do you have an idea to imitate the perform method?

Comment: I will but for now it's not completely validated unfortunately.. I'm still searching a was to stop this job if the source doesn't exist anymore.